# Saving canvas as image not saving some elements

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, canvas

I using HTML12Canvas library to save div as image

Here is my div

```
<div #monster class="monster-image" (click)="saveMonster()">
<div class="monster-container">
  <div>
    <div>
      <img style="width: auto; height: 400px" [src]="parts[0].partUrl + parts[5].partUrl" />
    </div>

  </div>
  <div style="z-index: 1;margin-top: -360px;">
    <img style="width: auto; height: 400px" [src]="parts[4].partUrl + getEmotionPicture(parts[4].partUrl)" />
  </div>
  <div style="z-index: 2;margin-top: -400px;">
    <img style="width: auto; height: 400px" [src]="parts[4].partUrl+'/' +parts[8].partUrl" />
  </div>
  <div style="margin-top: -400px;margin-left: 70px;">
    <img style="width: auto; height: 400px" [src]="parts[7].partUrl" />
  </div>

  <div style="margin-top: -489px">
    <img style="width: auto; height: 600px" [src]="parts[0].partUrl + 'body/Body.png'" />
  </div>
  <div style="margin-top: -520px">
    <img style="width: 400px; height: 400px" [src]="parts[0].partUrl + parts[1].partUrl" />
  </div>
  <div style="margin-top: -320px">
    <img style="width: 400px; height: 400px" [src]="parts[0].partUrl + parts[2].partUrl" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm saving it like this

```
saveMonster(): void {
html2canvas(this.monster.nativeElement).then(canvas => {
  this.canvas.nativeElement.src = canvas.toDataURL();
  this.downloadLink.nativeElement.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
  this.downloadLink.nativeElement.download = 'monster.png';
  this.downloadLink.nativeElement.click();
});
```

}

Monster is looking like this

[image]

But saving like this

[image]

So some elements not saving (z-index ones)

How I can fix this?

Comment: Did you mean `HTML2Canvas` instead of `HTML12Canvas`? Have you seen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51836736/html2canvas-z-index-not-effect

Comment: Yeah, I talked about this. Okay, I need those z-indexes, how I can fix this, with z-indexes? @KIKOSoftware

Comment: The suggestion is to change the order of the elements. In other words: Place the eyes and mouth as last.