# html2canvas not rendering text above SVG when it is displayed on browser with z-index correctly set

Tags: javascript, svg, z-index, html2canvas

I am using an `html2canvas` to generate and save posters. I currently have a custom SVG object of opacity 1 and z-index:1. On top of it, I have both `MaterialUI's Typography` and the normal `<h1>` tags with z-index set to a higher value. When I download the image, however the text does not appear.

Surprisingly, when I set the opacity of the custom SVG object to 0.5, I can see the text that still exists. I believe this might be a case of the z-index not being applied correctly.

Do provide any advice! The code block is below.
**Poster**

```
<Box
                sx={{
                    zIndex: 5,
                    justifyContent: "flex-start",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
                    width: "90%",
                    height: "35%",
                    padding: "1rem",
                    marginTop: "800px",
                    overflow: "hidden",
                }}
            >
                <h1 
                    >
                    {donationDetails.startDate}
                </h1>
                <Typography
                    color="white"
                    variant="h1"
                    gutterBottom
                    sx = {{zIndex: 5000}}
                    >
                    {donationDetails.startDate}
                </Typography>
                <Typography
                    color="white"
                    variant="h2"
                    gutterBottom
                    >
                    {donationDetails.name}
                </Typography>
                <Typography
                    color="white"
                    variant="h3"
                    gutterBottom
                    >
                    {donationDetails.location}
                </Typography>
                <Typography
                    color="white"
                    variant="h3"
                    gutterBottom
                    >
                    {donationDetails.donationItems}
                </Typography>

            </Box>
            <BasicOutline
                style={{
                    position: "absolute",
                    zIndex: 1,
                }}
            />
```

**HandleDownload Code**

```
    const handleDownload = () => {
        const box = document.getElementById('poster-box');
        if (!box) return;
        html2canvas(box)
            .then(canvas => {
                const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
                const link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = dataURL;
                link.download = 'poster.png';
                link.click();
            });
    };
```

Comment: `z-index` only works on positioned elements (i.e., their `position` has a value other than the default, `static`.) Is your library that you are using there supposed to add that on its own, when you specify stuff like `sx = {{zIndex: 5000}}` - or is it perhaps simply missing?

Comment: When you mention position, do you mean like the x,y coordinates position or just like z-index:5000? When I use the MaterialUI component, doing `sx = {{zIndex: 5000}}` helps me set the `z-index` to be `5000`. I suspect this issue may be that `html2canvas` is not rendering or treating the z-index properly but i am still troubleshooting

Comment: The `position` property needs to have a value other than the default, `static`, for a `z-index` to apply. (But if if looks like it should on the screen, then that is probably not the issue here - and really more likely a problem with html2canvas.)

Comment: I read from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51836736/html2canvas-z-index-not-effect#:~:text=html2canvas%20only%20cares%20about%20the,and%20divid3%20comes%20behind%20div2.) that `html2canvas` does not support z-index. I guess its time to find another way to overlay stuff WITHOUT using z-index...

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding `position:relative` following this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51836736/html2canvas-z-index-not-effect)

```
            <Box
                sx={{
                    justifyContent: "flex-start",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
                    width: "90%",
                    height: "35%",
                    padding: "1rem",
                    marginTop: "800px",
                    overflow: "hidden",
                    zIndex: "5000",
                    **position:"relative"**
                }}
            >
```